# How to change a color of QString item in QListView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a model of `QListView` and if I execute `model->data(idx);` it returns following `Qvariant`: `QVariant(QString, "Colorful text")`. Mine task is to edit the color of `Colorful text`.

I wanted to use smth like `model->setData(idx, *dunno what put here*, Qt::EditRole);`
I expect that I need to put color description in the place of `*dunno what put here*`, but I don't  know how.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the text color from `model->data(idx)`, you have use role `Qt::ForegroundRole` as an additional [parameter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) to return a `QVariant v`.

Then you can check your QVariant objects value as an integer for example with

```
int c = v.value<int>();
```

Finally set your new, modified color back in the model via

```
v.setValue(c);
model->setData(idx, const QVariant & value, Qt::ForegroundRole);
```

Comment: setData() only works if the model implements it - if the model is under your control, adapt data() to return the wanted color for ForegroundRole instead